# WCF Duplex Service - .Net Framing Error

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to create a duplex WCF service hosted in IIS 7.

I've set up the service in IIS and when navigate to the page in a browser I can see the WSDL info.

When I run it from my app I get:

**You have tried to create a channel to a service that does not support .Net Framing. It is possible that you are encountering an HTTP endpoint.**

In IIS I did the following:

1. APP POOL: ASP.NET 4.0 BINDINGS:
2. http:*:8026:,net.tcp:8026:* ENABLED
3. PROTOCOLS: http,net.tcp

**Here's the Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>

      <service name="InfoGov.Service.InfoGovService">
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" 
                  contract="InfoGov.Service.IInfoGovService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" 
                  binding="mexTcpBinding" 
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>

    </services>

      <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" 
                           httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Here's the client config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" 
                          sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>

      <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
          <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IInfoGovService" />
        </netTcpBinding>
      </bindings>

      <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8026/Service.svc" 
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IInfoGovService" 
                  contract="InfoGovProxy.IInfoGovService"
                  name="NetTcpBinding_IInfoGovService">
          <identity>
            <servicePrincipalName value="host/localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </client>

    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have Googled this error message. There's not much out there about it, and I looked at or tried some of the results with no success.

Can anyone see what's wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http::8026:,net.tcp:8026: ENABLED

There discussion of same problem. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c657ba19-5a0f-4cd6-962b-bfee69bdffad/does-not-support-net-framing?forum=wcf

For solution try to set different port for http and net.tcp protocols

Comment: Thanks. I already saw that post. I've checked the port. It's fine.